# CSS theme select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am running a local-only site, not on a webserver.

I have a couple CSS styles that are user-selectable. Using this code works perfectly if it's directly on the page.

```
<div class="themeselect">
<table><tr>
<td><a href="#" onclick="localStorage.setItem('style','screen');location.reload()"><i class="far fa-sun"></i></a></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="localStorage.setItem('style','highcontrast');location.reload()"><i class="far fa-moon"></i></a></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

I want to inject that HTML with a `<script src="js/themeselect.js"></script>` statement onto the page with an external JS file. I have tried this, but clicking the links doesn't do anything. I thought it might have something to do with the single and/or double quotes, but I've tried seemingly every combination of them, and I can't figure it out.

```
document.write("<div class='themeselect'>");
document.write("<table><tr>");
document.write("<td><a href='#' onclick='localStorage.setItem('style','screen');location.reload()'><i class='far fa-sun'></i></a></td>");
document.write("<td><a href='#' onclick='localStorage.setItem('style','highcontrast');location.reload()'><i class='far fa-moon'></i></a></td>");
document.write("</tr></table>");
document.write("</div>");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inject that HTML onto the page with an external JS file"? From a browser extension or bookmarklet? Or something else?

Comment: @BenHull Sorry. I have edited my question to explain what I meant by that.

Comment: You've multiple quoting issues. Please take a look at the Dev Console. You can fix these by escaping the inner quotes with the backslash.

Comment: `document.write()` will repeatedly write over all of the content of the document, you can't use successive calls like that. You could use `document.body.innerHTML = ...` and pass in all of the HTML as a string.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant The only errors I'm getting are CORS policy errors.

Comment: @skyline3000 Not at parsing time, though it's good to avoid `dw`.

Comment: `onclick='localStorage.setItem(\'style\',\'screen\'); ...'` etc. should fix your problem with quotes.

Comment: @skyline3000 I've used this document.write method with simple HTML, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it !!!

Check how i wrote 3rd and 4th line:

```
document.write("<div class='themeselect'>");
document.write("<table><tr>");
document.write("<td><a href='#' onclick=\"localStorage.setItem('style','screen');location.reload()\"><i class='far fa-sun'></i></a></td>");
document.write("<td><a href='#' onclick=\"localStorage.setItem('style','highcontrast');location.reload()\"><i class='far fa-moon'></i></a></td>");
document.write("</tr></table>");
document.write("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to inner text between body tag or container element:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<div class='themeselect'><table><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='localStorage.setItem('style','screen');location.reload()'><i class='far fa-sun'></i></a></td><td><a href='#' onclick='localStorage.setItem('style','highcontrast');location.reload()'><i class='far fa-moon'></i></a></td></tr></table></div>"
```

replace " to ' ,it work xD